# Ubuntu 22.04.3 does not detect second monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, hp

I have recently installed ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a new HP ZBook Power G9 laptop with an NVIDIA RTX A2000 graphics card. Additionally, I downloaded the NVIDIA driver 535 that was compatible with my system and manually changed from Intel to NVIDIA by typing `prime-select nvidia`.

Despite this fixing an existing issue (the laptop could not turn off with the intel in-build driver), I face a new one. The system does not recognize a second monitor, which I add using an HDMI. More specifically, I type `xrandr --listmonitors` and the output is

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1-1 1920/344x1080/193+0+0  eDP-1-1
```

If I understand correctly, the system does not even detect the second monitor.
Any suggestion?